# Installing external resources in Lambda Functions

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda and I want to install some external resources

```
npm install textapi
...
var TextAPI = require('textapi');
```

how can I install this when running my Lambda function. 
Note I know I have to upload a zip file just not sure what else is needed to get this running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zip file should contain your entire app, from a Node perspective that will include your `node_modules` folder.

See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

Comment: I understand that but after creating the modules directory where would I write the `npm install` code?

Comment: @KernElliott there is no `npm install` code to write in terms of a Lambda deployment, you would run `npm install` locally, package up your app and upload to AWS.